# React: Url changes, but page never moves

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Like the title, when I click one of the items, the URL changes, but the page never changes and just shows the same page.

**index.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**App.js**

```js
import axios from "axios";

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import ListItem from "./components/ListItem";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">

       // Here I am using Routes
       <Routes>
         <Route
          path="/test"
          element={data.map((list) => (
            <ListItem key={list.id} {...list} />
          ))}
         ></Route>
       </Routes>
    
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

***Test.js***

```js
import React from "react";

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

***Data***

```json
{
  id: recipe_id
  category: String 
  cookingSteps: [String] 
  cookingTime: Int 
  description: String 
  ingredients: [String] 
  kcal: Int
  name: String 
  servings: Int 
  spices: [String] 
  picture: String
}
```

I have tried `useNavigate` as well but did not work. What am I missing here?

I edited this question as it was somewhat blurred.

This is the source tree.

[image]

Would you let me know what I should address more?

[image: This is what I desire to see]

Comment: Are you rendering any routes from which to match to the URL path and render anything else? From the code snippet you've shared and the behavior you describe this is exactly what I would expect to happen. Seems you've a pretty trivial example, can you update and share a more representative code example for what you are trying to do?

Comment: Can you share your routes definition?

Comment: @DrewReese I have edited my question. I actually did not get the point of what I needed to share more as the code I shared is all that I wrote, so I added `source tree` and `Test.js`. Please let me know what I need to add more.

Comment: @Camilo What do you mean by `routes definition`?

Comment: So you are not rendering any `Route` components? These are what take a `path` prop to be matched against the URL and render a component for that path.

Comment: @DrewReese Nope, I am just using `Link` not `Route` yet. Can choose either `Link` or `Route` for the path, no..?

Comment: No. `Link` components link to a path, `Route` components render a component on a path. You need routes if you want to render different components on different pages/paths, and links if you want to navigate. Links change the URL, routes render content based on the URL.

Comment: @DrewReese I edited `App.js` according to what you let me know, but still have the same problem which does not change the page but only changes the url..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to render different content in response to the URL changing you also need to render your components into `Route` components matching each path.

Example App:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import ListItem from "./components/ListItem";
import About from "./components/About";
import Test from "./components/Test";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">

      /* Links for navigation */
      {data.map((list) => (
        // url changes here, but page got stuck in this App page
        <Link to="/test" key={list.id}>
          <ListItem {...list} />
        </Link>
      ))}

      /* Routes for rendering content */
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/test" element={<Test />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Demo

[image: Edit react-url-changes-but-page-never-moves]

> ```
> const About = () => <h1>About</h1>;
> const Test = () => {
>   return (
>     <div>
>       <p>Test</p>
>     </div>
>   );
> };
>
> export default function App() {
>   return (
>     <div className="App">
>       <ul>
>         <li>
>           <Link to="/about">About</Link>
>         </li>
>         <li>
>           <Link to="/test">Test</Link>
>         </li>
>       </ul>
>       <Routes>
>         <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
>         <Route path="/test" element={<Test />} />
>       </Routes>
>     </div>
>   );
> }
> ```

Comment: I indeed appreciate your answer, but still, I face the same issue. Will you check the question I just edited again?

Comment: @Uheny What is `ListItem`? Looks like you are mapping a few of them. Can you also include what `data` is?

Comment: @Uheny If you're doing exactly what this answer shows then there shouldn't be a problem. Assuming you're using react-router-dom v5. This answer assumes the ```ListItem``` is the navigation link buttons and the ```Test``` component is what you wish to render according to different urls as specified in the ```path``` prop of the ```Route``` component. Check your understanding and try your variables in the provided sandbox.

Comment: Yes, I did indeed initially assume that `data` was mapping to links for navigation, but at this point it could be anything, or completely irrelevant, IDK. That's why I added the overtly trivial sandbox demo with 2 links and 2 routes.

Comment: @DrewReese I just added the image I want to see. Hope this helps to comprehend my question ..

Comment: @Uheny Sure, you likely need to render a `Link` around ***each*** `ListItem` component you are mapping instead of one link around all of them. I assume that is what `data` is, what looks to be menu data.

Answer (score 0):

Route component renders the first one that matches the current URL, since it always matching the home '/' it will render the the first page.
-> Add 'exact' to your Route component and it will render the exact URL that matches the current URL

```
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {

    return (
     <>
       <div className="App">

         <Link to="/test">
           <ListItem />
         </Link>
      </div>
      <Switch>
         <Route exact path='/' />
         <Route path='/test' />
      </Switch>
   </>
   );
   }

export default App;
```

Comment: How can you possibly provide an answer when we've yet to see any `Route` components to know what order they are in? There was also a very recent major release that fundamentally changes how `Route` components are used and matched, eliminating the `exact` prop. Besides, in the older versions the correct solution is to use the correct route/path order instead of specifying the `exact` prop everywhere.

Comment: @Abraham Thank you for your answer, but I have got this error `'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.`